# Vertical tangent vertical cusp question?

Tags: calculus

I have two questions regarding vertical tangent and vertical cups.

The first one is determine whether the graph of $f(x)=(x+5)^{\frac{-2}{7}}$  has a vertical tangent or vertical cusp $c=-5$

I personally would say no because it is undefined at $c=-5$

My second questions is

Determine whether the graph of $f(x)=(x-4)^{\frac{3}{7}}$   has a vertical tangent of vertical cusp at  $c=4$

taking the derivative I got

$f(x)=\frac{3}{7}(x-4)^{\frac{-4}{7}}$

I would say this is is a vertical tangent because of the 4 exponent the limit of both left and right limits of c approach infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first function does indeed have a vertical tangent at $x = -5$. See the graph of your function, below: blue curve (Wolfram Alpha).

For your first function: $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[\large 7]{(x + 5)^2}}$$
$$f'(x) = -\frac{2}{7\sqrt[\large 7]{(x+5)^9}}$$

Note that the slope of the line tangent to the curve as $x \to -5^+$ DNE: the tangent becomes *vertical* because $f'(x) \to -\infty$, and the slope of the tangent line to the curve as $x\to -5^-$ DNE: the tangent becomes vertical because $f'(x) \to +\infty$.

In terms of testing for vertical tangency, a vertical tangent exists at a point $c$ whenever the limit of $f'(x) \to \infty\;$ and/or $\;f'(x) \to -\infty$ when approaching $c$ from the right, as well as from the left. The limits as one approaches a point of vertical tangenccy can both approach $+\infty$, both approach $-\infty$, or approach $+\infty$ from one direction and $-\infty$ from the other direction.

[image]

You're very much correct about your second function, there is a cusp at $x = 4$: for the very reasons you give.

See it as Wolfram plots the curve (blue):

$f(x) = (x-4)^{3/7}$.

[image]

Comment: I thought for my first c=-5 would make the  first function noncontinuous in its domain and not let it have a cusp?

Comment: but you see the same thing happens when c = 4, in your second function...$f(x)$ is not defined there.

Comment: but the first function is a fraction and the second one is not meaning it can be made zero?I dont know it is just my thought....

Comment: I see what you're saying. Nonetheless, we can have cusps occur where a function is not defined: indeed, the graph shows the discontinuity when $x \to -5$.

Comment: you are right the only reason I mentioned it is because in an exam in my class I am not allowed to use graphing calculator. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: In my experience the term "cusp" refers to corners.  I don't think it's standard to say that a vertical cusp occurs when the function blows up to $\infty$.  If a cusp occurs when the tangents are equal when they meet then the first function can't have a cusp since the tangents never meet.

Comment: A vertical tangent at $x = c$ when the slope approaches $-\infty$ and/or $+\infty$ as we approach $c$ from the right, and from the left. It was my mistake to use the terms "where they meet", it should have been as they approach the point at which the slope DNE: is vertical.

Comment: Clarification: A cusp is a point where the tangents as each branch approaches the point at which they meet approaches $\pm \infty$ (vertical tangent) and the point where they meet is defined.  A vertical tangent occurs when the limit approaching the point at which two branches would meet is $\pm \infty$, even if the function is undefined there.